# Python : Unable to pass log file name in KITTY

Tags: python-3.x, putty

I am trying to launch kitty using the below python code.

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen("kitty.exe sakthi@x.y.w.z -pw YYYY"
    "-cmd 'tail -2000f /apps/application/application.log'")
```

I am getting error as "unknown option "-2000f""

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to your question, but I presume you should have a space between `YYYY` and `-cmd`.

Comment: @khelwood I tried that also, still the same error

Comment: @martin-prikryl Can  u help ?